# WiFi will disconnect after every time my computer sleeps

Tags: networking, 16.04, suspend

Whenever my computer sleeps, my WiFi will disconnect, and then I have to reboot my computer for it to be able to connect to WiFi again.

I tried to look at the settings, but I cannot find where the problem is.

How should I make my computer not disconnect to WiFi after sleeping?

Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
 *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 9c:5c:8e:7b:4f:9c
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation    
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:122 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7004000-f7004fff memory:f7000000-f7003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlx803773b09281
       serial: 80:37:73:b0:92:81
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=4.4.0-38-generic firmware=1.4 ip=192.168.8.106 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Disconnecting from WiFi when a computer sleeps is relatively normal, but the fact that you can't reconnect is the odd part. Sounds kind of like the system is putting the wireless interface to sleep and not waking it up when you wake up your computer. Have you tried to check if the wireless interface was enabled after the wake-up?

Comment: Yes, wireless wifi is enabled when I check it, but it does not connect.

Comment: Does it help to do: `sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: No sorry, it does not help. All it did was disconnect my wifi, and it did not connect again. So I had tor reboot to get wifi connected again.

Comment: Please list your computer hardware and wireless card by using the command "lshw -C network"